# Создать экземпляр объекта WebControl Awesomium в фоновом потоке

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await, awesomium

Нашел почти все по работе с этим компонентом, кроме одного - как мне создать экземпляр объекта в фоновом потоке?

Если создавать так:

```
WebControl browser = new WebControl();
browser.Source = new Uri("http://wtfismyip.com/text");
```

то не хочет отправлять запросы(или принимать ответ, так и не понял). Никаких исключений, просто browser.HTML пуст.

Работает только так:

```
WebControl browser = new WebControl();
Controls.Add(browser);
browser.Source = new Uri("http://wtfismyip.com/text");
```

но тогда нужно врываться в UI-поток.

Все бы ничего, если их нужно 2 или 3, но выполнение вот такого кода:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    browsers[i] = new WebControl();
    webPreferences[i] = new WebPreferences(true);
    webSessionProvider[i] = new WebSessionProvider();
    webPreferences[i].ProxyConfig = proxy[i];
    webSessionProvider[i].Preferences = new WebSessionProvider();
    webSessionProvider[i].Views.Add(browsers[i]);

    Controls.Add(browsers[i]);
}
```

может заморозить форму на 30-60сек(точно не замерял, но Windows успевает пометить приложение, как "не отвечающее"). Как можно создать и использовать этот компонент полностью в фоновом потоке?

Чтобы было что-то вроде:

```
private async Task Do()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        browsers[i] = new WebControl();
        webPreferences[i] = new WebPreferences(true);
        webSessionProvider[i] = new WebSessionProvider();
        webPreferences[i].ProxyConfig = proxy[i];
        webSessionProvider[i].Preferences = webPreferences[i];
        webSessionProvider[i].Views.Add(browsers[i]);
        browsers[i].Source = new Uri("http://wtfismyip.com/text");

        while (browsers[i].IsLoading)
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: UI-компоненту вряд ли получится использовать не в UI-потоке. А зачем вам, простите, 50 браузеров?

Comment: Собственноручно сделанный сабмиттер. :)
Посадил бы все на гет\пост, но через браузер намного проще и эффективнее в плане эмуляции. То есть его совсем никак без UI нельзя использовать?
А можно создать, например, 50 скрытых форм с браузером, но так, чтобы основная форма была свободна и не замораживалась?

Comment: В любом случае всё идёт через UI-поток, проблема не в том, видна форма или нет. Вы можете, конечно, создать 50 UI-потоков, но не уверен, что это тоже не будет тормозить. В любом случае это разгрузить основной UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение, может кому будет интересно. Я не мог открыть документацию Awesomium, у них там что-то с сайтом, но смог обойти это и все-таки почитал. В итоге, можно использовать не контрол WebControl, а WebView. Итоговый код будет выглядеть так:

```
        WebSession s = WebCore.CreateWebSession( new WebPreferences()
        {
            ProxyConfig = "127.0.0.1:900"
        } );
        WebView vw = WebCore.CreateWebView(1024, 768, s);

        vw.Source = new Uri("http://wtfismyip.com");
        while (!vw.IsDocumentReady && vw.HTML == "" && vw.IsLoading)// Тут поставил много проверок, так как одна иногда не срабатывает.
        {
            WebCore.Update();// VS ругается и говорит, что метод уже устарел, но он работает.
        }
```

По поводу WebCore.Update() - в документации есть метод Run(), но я еще не разобрался как он действует, если есть информация как его использовать - буду рад описанию.

И еще, есть странности при использовании async - если делать так:

```
    private async Task Do()
    {
        WebSession s = WebCore.CreateWebSession( new WebPreferences()
        {
            ProxyConfig = "127.0.0.1:900"
        } );
        WebView vw = WebCore.CreateWebView(1024, 768, s);

        vw.Source = new Uri("http://wtfismyip.com");
        while (!vw.IsDocumentReady && vw.HTML == "" && vw.IsLoading)// Тут поставил много проверок, так как одна иногда не срабатывает.
        {
            WebCore.Update();// VS ругается и говорит, что метод уже устарел, но он работает.
        }
    }
```

то UI-поток занят, но если работать через Backgroundworker - то все отлично. Интересны были бы любые мысли по этому поводу.